# Laravel form post to controller

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I am new to Laravel and I'm having trouble with posting data to a controller. I couldn't find the corresponding documentation. I want to something similar in Laravel that I do in C# MVC.

```
<form action="/someurl" method="post">
<input type="text" name="someName" />
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeUrl(string someName)
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should use route.

your `.html`

```
<form action="{{url('someurl')}}" method="post">
<input type="text" name="someName" />
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

in `routes.php`

```
Route::post('someurl', 'YourController@someMethod');
```

and finally in `YourController.php`

```
public function someMethod(Request $request)
{
   dd($request->all());  //to check all the datas dumped from the form
   //if your want to get single element,someName in this case
   $someName = $request->someName; 
}
```

Answer (score 13):

This works best

```
<form action="{{url('someurl')}}" method="post">
 @csrf
<input type="text" name="someName" />
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

in `web.php`

```
Route::post('someurl', 'YourController@someMethod');
```

and in your Controller

```
public function someMethod(Request $request)
{
   dd($request->all());  //to check all the datas dumped from the form
   //if your want to get single element,someName in this case
   $someName = $request->someName; 
}
```

Comment: This answer is mostly a copy of the accepted answer. Why does this work better than the accepted answer?

Comment: @Lexib0y Addition of `@csrf` prevents 419 "Page Expired" error