# post form action to controller in laravel

Tags: laravel, forms, action

First of all I want to say that my problem is very similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37612280/laravel-form-post-to-controller), only the answer is not working in my case.

I am trying to connect my form action to my UserController. it's an update avatar function. Here's what it look like.

[image]

in my profile/show.blade

```
<div class="col-md-12 justify-content-center">
    <form action="{{ action('UsersController@update_avatar') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf

    </form>
</div>
```

UsersController

```
public function avatar()
{
    $user = Auth::User();
    return view('dashboard.profile'.$user->id,compact('user',$user));
}

public function update_avatar(Request $request){

    $request->validate([
        'avatar' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

    $user = Auth::User();

    $folder = 'avatars';
    Storage::delete($folder.'/'.$user->avatar); 

    $avatarName = $user->id.'_avatar'.'.'.request()->avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $request->avatar->storeAs('avatars',$avatarName);

    $user->avatar = $avatarName;
    $user->save();

    return back()
        ->with('success','You have successfully upload image.');
}
```

routes/web.php

```
Route::get('dashboard/profile/{{profile}}', 'Dashboard\\UsersController@avatar');
Route::post('dashboard/profile/{{profile}}', 'Dashboard\\UsersController@update_avatar');
```

here's the error I am receiving

[image]

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: What's your `profile` model look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change these routes:

```
Route::get('dashboard/profile/{{profile}}', 'Dashboard\\UsersController@avatar');
Route::post('dashboard/profile/{{profile}}', 'Dashboard\\UsersController@update_avatar');
```

To these:

```
Route::get('dashboard/profile/{{profile}}', 'UsersController@avatar')->name('user.avatar');
Route::post('dashboard/profile/{{profile}}', 'UsersController@update_avatar')->name('user.update_avatar');
```

And in your form use *route* instead of *action*

```
<form action="{{ route('user.update_avatar') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
</form>
```

Comment: Hi @charles. it says "Missing required parameters for [Route: user.update_avatar] [URI: dashboard/profile/{{profile}}]"

Comment: It says missing parameters because you're telling Laravel to look for a `profile` id in your Route, but don't actually pass it one ( or use one ).

Comment: It works by updating  your suggested route into: Route::get('dashboard/profile/', 'Dashboard\\UsersController@avatar')->name('user.avatar');
Route::post('dashboard/profile/', 'Dashboard\\UsersController@update_avatar')->name('user.update_avatar'); thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can try do something like this:

```
Route::post('dashboard/profile','Dashboard\UsersController@update_avatar')->name(profile.update);
```

and use it in the form like this:

```
<form action="{{ route('profile.update') }}">
```